# Custom UINavigationBar items positioned incorrectly when changing default bar height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I subclassed UINavigationBar and change its height according to device. Everything works perfectly until I add buttons. If default height changes, buttons are not positioned in center but at the bottom.

### RevUINavigationBar.m:

```
#import "RevUINavigationBar.h"
#import "Utils.h"

#define MAIN_COLOR_COMPONENTS       { 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0 }
#define LIGHT_COLOR_COMPONENTS      { 0.263, 0.263, 0.263, 1.0, 0.263, 0.263, 0.263, 1.0 }

@implementation RevUINavigationBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
     return self;
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // emulate the tint colored bar
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGFloat topComponents[8] = MAIN_COLOR_COMPONENTS;
    CGGradientRef topGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(myColorspace, topComponents, locations, 2);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, topGradient, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height/2), 0);
    CGGradientRelease(topGradient);

    CGFloat botComponents[8] = LIGHT_COLOR_COMPONENTS;
    CGGradientRef botGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(myColorspace, botComponents, locations, 2);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, botGradient,
                            CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height/2), CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height), 0);
    CGGradientRelease(botGradient);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorspace);    

    // top Line
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width, 0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    // bottom line
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    int navigationBarHeight = 44;

    if ([Utils isIpad] == YES)
        navigationBarHeight = 88;

    return CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, navigationBarHeight);
}
@end
```

Adding buttons:

```
- (void)showCustomNavBarItems
{
    NSMutableArray *leftItems = [NSMutableArray new];
    if (self != [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0])
    {
        UIImage *backBtnImg = [UIImage imageNamedSmart:@"BackB"];
        UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backBarButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [backBtn setImage:backBtnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backBtnImg.size.width, backBtnImg.size.height);
        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];                                       
        backButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        [leftItems addObject:backButton];
    }

    UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamedSmart:@"Logo"]];
    UIBarButtonItem *logo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:logoView];

    [leftItems addObject:logo];    

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftItems;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: I'm not surprised you get this kind of side effects when trying to modify very basic properties of [iOS] UI classes.  Apparently you've just broken the [auto-]layout.  I think you should build your own navigation controller from scratch if you'd want a different size.  Then, navigation controller are such a basic thing, that you'd better not change the size; it will make your app look off.

Comment: Can i just fix the auto-layout?

Comment: As said, you should implement your own, or use some existing (someone must have done this) open source implementation.  Alternatively you could try what happens if you change the `frame` of your buttons, but this is actually really bad and hacky.  Look [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) for example.

Comment: Found a solution much easier then implementing this control from scratch. Just overrided function layoutSubViews and set all my controls to a correct positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to override function layoutSubViews and set all my controls to a correct positions:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
        view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,
                                self.frame.size.width / 2 - view.frame.size.width / 2,
                                view.frame.size.width,
                                view.frame.size.height);
}
```